# Export SQL Server Management Studio Display Settings

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I can't find an option to export my custom SQL Server 2008 custom font and background changes like you can for example with Visual Studio.

Maybe I'm missing it but maybe this isn't possible in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: It would be great to tell you, but we can't: what version of SQL Server are you using? Are you talking about Query Analyzer or Management Studio or some 3rd party product that is literally called "SQL Server Analyzer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2008 and 2008 R2, this isn't possible natively. There are [hacks around](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqltools/thread/00552b92-3d47-477e-aafc-fb2480519fb3) if you google. In Denali, you will be able to do this using a new wizard under Tools > Import and Export Settings.